# ActionScript Error - Line 19 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightparen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm pretty new to action script and i'm following a actionscript tutorial. I keep getting this error and i don't know where i'm going wrong. I've searched google and looked everywhere but can't seem to fix it.

```
Error: Line 19 1084: Syntax error: expecting identifier before rightparen.
```

Code:

```
package  {
import flash.display.Sprite;

public class Main extends Sprite {
    private var gameField:Array;
    var rows:uint = 6;
    var columns:uint = 7;


    public function Main() {
        prepareField();
    }

    private function prepareField():void {
        gameField=new Array();
        for (var i:uint=0; i<rows; i++) {
            gameField[i]=new Array();
            for (var j:unit=0; j<columns; j++) {
                gameField[i].push(0););
            }
        }
        trace("the field: "+gameField);
    }

  }

}
```

Line 19:

```
gameField[i].push(0););
```

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear. You should delete the extra `);` at the end of that line. (And probably report the typo to the author of the tutorial.)

Comment: I've tried that and now i'm getting another error:

Comment: Line 18 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: unit.

Comment: That is probably `j:uint`. I guess this would be the point when I would look for a different tutorial. ;)

Comment: Changed it to an integer and it's working fine now. Thanks

Comment: Any reason you're going with ActionScript/Flash and not HTML5?